# Attach an image to new posts

Tags: plugin-development, attachments

I am trying to attach an image to the body of a post.

- The post is created.
- The image is added to the Media Library.
- The thumbnail is added to the post.
- The images do not get added?

```
$attachment = array(
         'guid' => $image_url, 
         'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
         'post_title' => $c_img . ' - ' . $key,
         'post_status' => 'inherit',
         'post_date'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
         'post_parent' => $post_id // Does not seem to add it to the parrent???
    );

// adding image to media library
$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $image_path);
$attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $image_path);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);

// adding thumbnail, works fine?
if ($key == 0) {
  add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id, true);
}
```

Comment: How do you get `$post_id`?

Comment: Created the post

Comment: $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

Comment: Is the image added at all as an attachment? You can easily check if `$attachment_id` by adding `var_dump( $attachment_id );` If it is `0`, then the attachment was not successfully added.

Comment: Is the file already within the `uploads` directory?

Comment: In addition, your issue may be that `add_post_meta(...,...,..., true)` will not change the field value if it already exists. Try using `update_post_meta` as it will update the value if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

The featured image doesn't get added to [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content). You can show it inside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) with [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail). If you want to add the image to `the_content` you can manipulate it via the filter [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content), see the example section on the codex page.

Comment: This is an upload loop, can i just the content for the post here?

Comment: Ok, well, this loop creates posts, and registers images from the upload dir, in the media database.

I am trying to include the image, that i just added to the media datbase, in to the newly created posts content, i mean, do i have to set the <img> tags for the post or is there some other way to achive this?

Comment: There is a difference between *a loop* and *The Loop* in wordpress, read up on that. Adding it to the  `post_content` on your `wp_insert_post()` call would be a solution or you filter `the_content` - in both cases you want to add the `img` tags. @IvanRistic